# What does "run at null:-1" mean in Apache Spark WEB UI?

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

From my Apache WEB UI dashboard. I've seen a lot of this `run at null:-1` jobs, several actually in my particular project that comprises basically of: connect to a JDBC PostgreSQL Server, fetch some tables, creating some temp tables and do some aggregations with `org.apache.spark.sql.Cube()` method.

Link to image: [RunAtNull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEfgM.png)

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Spark. Could you raise ticket in Spark JIRA or write about this on Spark user list?

Comment: I'll do it in the next hours. Thanks a lot for the response.

Comment: Seeing the same problem here. Did you ever create a ticket on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK/, @Emiliano? (I tried searching, to no avail; JIRA is a train wreck.)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I haven't do it but the ticket it's up now. The ticket is: SPARK-18382. Please sorry.

Comment: @chbrown You can take a look at, [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18382), it is not a major bug they said, more like a `cosmetic bug`. I'll try to do some research

Comment: @Emiliano right, my jobs/tasks still seem to run alright despite the cryptic / ominous message, but thanks for creating an actual issue.